# Using import sys and sys.argv, count the number of unique vowels in a string arguments from the commandline

Tags: python

I have the following task:

> Import the `sys` module to use sys.argv. Create a function with a string parameter that will print the number of **unique** vowels in the string regardless of whether it has uppercase, lowercase, numbers, spaces or unique characters.

**For example:**

```
Test 1: python3 countVowels.py Batman 
Test 2: python3 countVowels.py 'The Dark Knight'
Test 3: python3 countVowels.py 'oaIeuOnI t_#pA'
```

Use sys.argv for the arguments; do not manually insert the arguments to find the number of unique vowels.

**For example, do not do this:**

```
print(count_vowels("G0tham City 3ni$peo"))
```

**I have the following code, some of which has been derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542378/17769815):**

```
import sys

def count_vowels(text):
    letter = set(text.lower())

    count = 0
    for vowel in 'aeiou':
        if vowel in letters:
            count += 1
    return count 

print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1:]))
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "countVowels.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "countVowels.py", line 4, in count_vowels
    letter = set(text.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: And what is your question?  Does this work?

Comment: As the error message says, `sys.argv[1:]` is a _list_ of arguments.  If you intended to pass a single argument, use `sys.argv[1]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue: You are iterating through a list

```py
print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1:])) # "1:" returns a list, not index 1
```

This should just be ```python
print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1]))

Second issue: you are iterating through the wrong thing

```py
import sys

def count_vowels(text):
    letter = set(text.lower())

    count = 0
    for vowel in 'aeiou': #you should iterate through letter not "aeiou"
        if vowel in letters: #
            count += 1
    return count
```

try this instead:

```py
import sys

def count_vowels(text):
    word = set(text.lower()) #rename for easier identification

    count = 0
    for letter in word: #iterate through word
        if letter in "aeiou": #if "letter" is a vowel, increment
            count += 1
    return count 

print(count_vowels(sys.argv[1]))
```

That should work.

Also, to explain `set()`. This function returns a set with each unique value in it. For example:

```py
set([1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3])
```

would return:

```py
{1,2,3}
```

`set()` does the same for characters. Example:

```py
set("aaabccc")
```

returns:

```
{"a","b","c"}
```

Using set means your function only deals with non re-occuring characters, so you don't have to keep track of whether you have already counted a vowel. Else, for example, you would have to keep track of every "a" that comes through otherwise you would count it more than once.

Comment: It's probably worth calling attention to exactly what `set()` does.

Comment: @CryptoFool look at OP description. each *unique* vowel

Comment: [I wrote this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542378/17769815). Since the question asks for the number of _unique_ values, we can use a set to store all the letters that appear in the string to make it faster. [That being said, OP should have given some attribution.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)

Comment: All good, just don't make it a habit. Also, if these questions are related to homework assignments, make sure that you cite my answer and this answer in your submission. We're not here to facilitate academic dishonesty.